# How can I flash the kernel on my Cubieboard

Tags: kernel, cubieboard

The flash-kernel command fails with "Unsupported platform" on my cubieboard. How can I add support for the Cubieboard?

Comment: You can use http://linux-sunxi.org/Cubieboard as starting point. And maybe [Armbian](https://docs.armbian.com/#supported-boards).